# What's wrong with this implementation? I'm unable to override the style

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to override the fontSize of my subheading text. I'm getting the style prop in my component. I've checked it by using console.log and it's fine. But my styles are not implementing. What's wrong with my code. Please help.

Here's the component called Subheading,

```
function SubHeadingText({children, style}) {
  return (
    <Text style={[{fontSize: style.fontSize}, styles.textSubHeading]}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textSubHeading: {
    fontSize: 19,
    color: colors.black,
  },
});
```

and here's I'm passing the style

```
<SubHeadingText style={{fontSize: 14}}>
    All fields are required to register with App.
</SubHeadingText>
```

Comment: Your style prop is wrong: You need `style={[ styles.textSubHeading, style ]}`

Comment: @ChrisG In react native, the style attribute can have multiple styles on it and they get smashed down to a single one in array order.  See [RN style docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style) "You can also pass an array of styles - the last style in the array has precedence, so you can use this to inherit styles".

Comment: @zero298 Just found that, fixed my comment

Comment: Order of precedence is also mentioned right in the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/style

Comment: @ChrisG also, just for note, spreading what gets returned from `StyleSheet.create` will actually cause more problems because you end up spreading the id of a stylesheet instead of actual properties.  This was the source of a lot of confusion whenever I was working on my last RN project.

Comment: @zero298 Good to know, and shows that reading the docs is important ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip the order of the styles, they are applied in order and you override it with the constant stylesheet:

See [React Native Style Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style):

> You can also pass an array of styles - the last style in the array has
> precedence, so you can use this to inherit styles

```
function SubHeadingText({children, style}) {
  return (
    <Text style={[
      styles.textSubHeading, // Needs to be applied first so next line overrides
      {fontSize: style.fontSize}, // Will override styles.textSubHeading fontSize
    ]}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
}
```

Comment: If the entire answer is basically a link to the docs, maybe consider not posting it as answer?

Comment: @ChrisG I'll meet you in the middle and post it as a CW.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I saw my mistake just after I posted the question. Thanks again.